# Attaching to an email in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell script:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path D:\temp\Audit.csv | Where-Object {$_.PrivateLabelSeqId -eq "602"} | Measure-Object
$Fun = $csv.Count
$mailBody = 
@"
There are <b> $Fun </b> available!
"@

Send-MailMessage -Body $mailBody -BodyAsHtml `
-From "mail@mail.com" -To "mailto@mail.com" `
-Subject "Audit - FUN" -Encoding $([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) `
-Attachment "D:\temp\Audit.csv" `
-SmtpServer "192.0.0.20"
```

Yet I do not get any email sent out. Without the attachment however, it seems to work just fine. Any ideas on how to resolve this? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you get an error? Does this work? dir D:\temp\Audit.csv | Send-MailMessage -Body $mailBody -BodyAsHtml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem once, i solved it by using System.Net.Mail instead.

```
$filenameAndPath = (Resolve-Path .\$file).ToString()
$from = 'mail@mail.com'
$to = "mailto@mail.com" `
$Subject "Audit - FUN" -Encoding $([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) 
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Net') | out-null

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($from, $to, $subject, $subject)
$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($filenameAndPath, 'text/plain')
$message.Attachments.Add($attachment)
$smtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
$smtpClient.host = '192.0.0.20'
$smtpClient.Send($message)
```

To read more about System.Net.Mail.Attachement Class
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx